# SQLite - float granularity breaking unique contraint?

Tags: sqlite, floating-point

I'm using SQLite 3.25.2 on Windows, downloaded the latest precompiled binaries from the official page https://sqlite.org/download.html

Executing the following code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestReal;
CREATE TABLE TestReal(A REAL UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807.0);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807.0 - 1);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807.0 - 2);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807.0 - 3);
```

fails as expected, since 9223372036854775807.0 is 2^63, these numbers are way out of the range where all integers are exactly representable as doubles. I mean

```
sqlite> select 9223372036854775807.0 = 9223372036854775807.0 - 1;
1
sqlite> select 9223372036854775807.0 = 9223372036854775807.0 - 512;
1
```

And column A is unique, so it makes perfect sense to print a 'UNIQUE constraint failed: TestReal.A' message. But there seems to be an unintended workaround

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestReal;
CREATE TABLE TestReal(A REAL UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807 - 1);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807 - 2);
INSERT INTO TestReal values (9223372036854775807 - 3);
```

runs without any problems. The following queries confirm that the table now has exactly 4 values inserted, but only one distinct value, despite of having a unique constraint

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM TestReal;
9.22337203685478e+18
9.22337203685478e+18
9.22337203685478e+18
9.22337203685478e+18
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT(A) FROM TestReal;
9.22337203685478e+18
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE TestReal(A REAL UNIQUE);
```

So my question is: is this a bug in SQLite? Or do I not understand correctly what 'unique' actually means?

Comment: I don't know how exactly SQLite compares `INTEGER` and `REAL` values to each other, but I can duplicate this issue on my machine, and also note that `SELECT 9223372036854775807 = 9223372036854775807.0` returns 0 (false).

Comment: Thanks for testing it! I think you are onto something with your example, because I can indeed insert both of those values into a REAL UNIQUE column, like they were different, still a DISTINCT(A) only yields one value.
It looks like values are first tested for uniqueness, and only THEN are converted to the given column type, which changes the way they should be tested for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of SQLite 3.29.0 it's settled, this was never the intended behavior, but a bug. The error is still present in 3.28.0, but not in 3.29.0, in the newest versions both of my code snippets fail as expected.

This is the commit containing the fix:
https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/9b0915272f4d4052

I confirmed it by manually applying this commit on 3.28.0 source code, and replacing `MEM_IntReal` with `(MEM_Int | MEM_Real)`.

The error ticket was opened after the possible error was reported here on the official SQLite mailing list:
https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg115214.html

I also reported it, in fact a bit earlier but my report didn't garner that much attention:
https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg112655.html